# jQuery Tabs panels are not animating smoothly

Tags: jquery

I am learning jquery after some basic practice I trying to make jquery tabs with some content in it, they are working but there are few issues with them. They don't slide smooth and content div dose not follow tab, for example it shows content div 3 on tab 1

HTML :

```
<div id="mainDiv">    
    <div id="tabs">    
        <ul>        
            <li><div class="divClass active" title ="1" >Tab1</div></li>
            <li><div class="divClass" title="2" >Tab2</div></li>
            <li><div class="divClass" title="3" >Tab3</div></li>
        </ul>
    </div>    
    <div id="contentDiv">
        <div class="contDiv panelActive" id="1">div 1</div>
        <div class="contDiv" id="2">div 2</div>
        <div class="contDiv" id="3">div 3</div>
    </div>                       
</div>
```

JQUERY :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#mainDiv #tabs ul li div ").on('click', function(){        
    var $attrVal = $(this).closest('#mainDiv');

    $attrVal.find('div.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');

    var $contShow = $(this).attr('title');

    $attrVal.find('#contentDiv>.contDiv.panelActive').slideUp(500, 
    showNextPanel);

    function showNextPanel() {
        $(this).removeClass('panelActive');

        $('#'+$contShow).slideDown(500, function() {
            $(this).addClass('panelActive');
        });
        }

        });

        });
```

Comment: o.o, are you sure its not how your computer renders them? i just copied your code and put it into jsfiddle and it seems to not have the issues you state in your post: http://jsfiddle.net/swm53ran/320/ (except that it shows all the tabs initially)

Comment: all the content div's you mean

Comment: tabs are changing their color in css, may be you notice that all div's are showing, I want to show div1 by default when i load the page